# how to recover deleted photos on Mac, that were earlier imported from Iphone?

Tags: photos, ios

After importing picture files from my Iphone, I copied the lot onto my external drive & deleted these files from my Iphone & Photos app. But unfortunately I lost the drive. Is there a way to recover those files on Mac, which were once imported?